# Linq to Entities - limiting the results of a search form to only those results that match all choices for a many to many relationship

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have 3 tables in my application

**Employee**
EmployeeID
EmployeeName
DOB

**Skills**
SkillID
Description

**EmployeeSkills**
EmployeeID
SkillID
YearsExperience

What's the best way to write a linq query to allow a user to simultaneously search on information in the Employee table and limit the results to those who match all skills chosen? I've got no problem when it's one skill, or any skill out of those chosen, but I'm stuck on how to only return when they match all. The best I've managed so far is a hideous mass of intersects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with using a very simple version of your table structure:

```
var q = from e in Employee
    join es in EmployeeSkills
    on e.EmployeeID equals es.EmployeeID
    join s in Skills
    on es.SkillID equals s.SkillID
    group s by e into grouping
    where !skillsToMatch.Except(grouping.Select(x => x.SkillID)).Any()
    select grouping.Key;
```

Where 'skillsToMatch' is an IEnumerable of SkillID's you want the Employee's to have.  It will return all Employees that at least have all the skills in 'skillsToMatch'.

If you have [linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) installed you can see how this works with my dummy data with this script:

```
var Employee = new [] {
    new { EmployeeID = 1 },
    new { EmployeeID = 2 },
    new { EmployeeID = 3 },
    new { EmployeeID = 4 },
    new { EmployeeID = 5 },
};

var Skills = new [] {
    new { SkillID = 1 },
    new { SkillID = 2 },
    new { SkillID = 3 },
    new { SkillID = 4 },
    new { SkillID = 5 },
};

var EmployeeSkills = new [] {
    new { EmployeeID = 1, SkillID = 4 },
    new { EmployeeID = 1, SkillID = 5 },
    new { EmployeeID = 3, SkillID = 4 },
    new { EmployeeID = 3, SkillID = 1 },
    new { EmployeeID = 5, SkillID = 3 },
};

var skillsToMatch = new [] { 4, 5 };

var q = from e in Employee
join es in EmployeeSkills
on e.EmployeeID equals es.EmployeeID
join s in Skills
on es.SkillID equals s.SkillID
group s by e into grouping
where !skillsToMatch.Except(grouping.Select(x => x.SkillID)).Any()
select grouping.Key;

q.Dump();
```

Play around by changing the 'skillsToMatch' array to see if it provides the behavior you seek.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop over the sleected skills, then add a Where(x=>x.Skills.Contails(skill)) to the query for each skill requested.  This will eliminate each employee that doesn't have every skill.